# How to validate sum of fields in a fieldset

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate my product form, basically in each fieldset there are 7 inputs and these can only validate if they all sum up to 7. I can only get this working for just one fieldset but when there are multiple fieldsets on the page I don't know how to get this to work. Any help is much appreciated as I am a newbie.

Here is my fiddle http://tinyurl.com/nst5p5m

HTML:

```
 <form class="table">
      <fieldset>

        <table width="100%" border="0" style="margin-right:10%;">
          <tr valign="top">
            <td >
              <table cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                  <td>Answer 1</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_1" name="meals_1" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Answer 2</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_2" name="meals_2" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 3</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_3" name="meals_3" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 4</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_4" name="meals_4" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 5</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_5" name="meals_5" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 6</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_6" name="meals_6" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>


                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 7</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_7" name="meals_7" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
                <tr id="summeals"><td>Total:</td><td><input type="number" value="0" max="100" name="sum" class="sum" size="5" disabled />

                </td></tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>

        <table width="100%" border="0" style="margin-right:10%;">
          <tr valign="top">
            <td >
              <table cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                  <td>Answer 1</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_1" name="meals_1" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Answer 2</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_2" name="meals_2" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 3</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_3" name="meals_3" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 4</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_4" name="meals_4" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 5</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_5" name="meals_5" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 6</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_6" name="meals_6" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>


                  <tr>
                  <td>Answer 7</td>
                  <td><input type="number" id="meals_7" name="meals_7" value="" max="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
                <tr id="summeals"><td>Total:</td><td><input type="number" value="0" max="100" name="sum" class="sum" size="5" disabled />

                </td></tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       <input type="submit" class="btn" value="submit" id="button-cart" name="continue" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>

<div class="error"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  // Hide the jQuery Mobile button
  $('#button-cart').closest('.btn').hide();
  // Look for a change on inputs that start with "q8"
  $('input[name^="meals"]').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    // Loop through all inputs with names that start
    // with "q8" and sum their values
    $('input[name^="meals"]').each(function() {
      sum+= parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    // Set the sum
    $('.sum').val(sum);

    // If the sum == 7 then show the button otherwise
    // hide it
    if (sum == 7) {
      $('#button-cart').closest('.btn').show();
        $("div.error").html("Your percentage fields must sum to 7.").hide();   
    }
    else {
      $('#button-cart').closest('.btn').hide();
        $("div.error").html("Your percentage fields must sum to 7.").show(); 
    }      
  });
});
```

Comment: please add relevant code in question so that if link get lost in future question will still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : iterate all input inside particular fieldset and calculate sum. Then verify each sum fields and show / hide button accordigly.

```
$(function() {
  // Hide the jQuery Mobile button
  $('#button-cart').hide();
  //put error message
  $("div.error").html("Your percentage fields must sum to 7.").hide();
  // Look for a change on inputs that name start with "meals"
  $('input[name^="meals"]').on("change keyup",function() {
    //get parent fieldset
    var $fieldSet = $(this).closest('fieldset');

    var sum = 0;
    //sum up all input inside fieldset
    $fieldSet.find('input[name^="meals"]').each(function() {
      sum+= parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    // Set the sum
    $fieldSet.find('.sum').val(sum);

    var allSumAreSeven = true;

    //check all sum fields and update flag allSumAreSeven 
    $('form.table').find('.sum').each(function(){
          if(parseInt($(this).val())!=7)
              allSumAreSeven = false;
    });
    // If allSumAreSeven = true, then show button otherwise hide it
    if (allSumAreSeven) {
      $('#button-cart').show();
      $("div.error").hide();       
    }
    else {
      $('#button-cart').hide();
      $("div.error").show();       
    }   
  });
});
```

**[JFFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xnvtomL6/6/)**

Comment: thanks for your help, that's working great. Just one question how do I hide the error message until somebody starts to change the quantity in one of the input boxes?

Comment: you need to call `.hide()` for error message inside `$(function() ...` block. See my updated answer.

Comment: happy to help you :) .. you can accept this answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the proper `elements` to update the `.sum` and `validate` them. You need to validate `inputs` of respective `fieldset`. Just make some changes in your `change` functionality and this should work.

```
$('input[name^="meals"]').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input[name^="meals"]').each(function({
            //loop only those elements which are inside that fieldset
            sum+= parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        // Set the sum
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.sum').val(sum);
        //get `.sum`  belonging to `fieldset` to which current input belongs
        // If the sum == 7 then show the button otherwise
        // hide it
        if (sum == 7) {
            $('#button-cart').closest('.btn').show();
            $("div.error").html("Your percentage fields must sum to 7.").hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#button-cart').closest('.btn').hide();
            $("div.error").html("Your percentage fields must sum to 7.").show();
        }
});
```

**[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xnvtomL6/8/)**